# how to use attributes to show-hide elements with CSS3 transitions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visibility, css-transitions

I'm using CSS3 transitions like this:

```
if( pop.attr('status') == 'visible' ) {
    pop.attr('status', 'hidden')            
        // pop transition - class of "pop" was added when showing the element
       .addClass('reverse out')
       .hide('fast')                    
   }

// clean up pop() transition 
window.setTimeout( function() {
   pop.removeClass('reverse out pop');
   }, 350);
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to handle visiblity through the status attribute AND STILL have the CSS3 transition? I'd rather use some CSS rule like so:

```
pop[status="hidden"]   { display: none; }
pop[status="visible"]  { display: block; }
```

than using hide() and show(), because I'm sometimes ending up having visible elements with status set to *hidden*, which fails my script

Using only status to determine visiblity thus makes more sense (and less confusion) for me.

Thanks for some input!

**EDIT**:
I'm showing the element like this:

```
    pop.attr('status','visible')         
        // pop() transition
        .addClass('ui-panel-active pop in')
        .show('fast')

    // clean up pop transition
    window.setTimeout( function() { 
       $popPanel.removeClass('in');
       }, 350);
```

*Status* is an attribute I assign to the element to monitor whether it's visible or not. I'm using the CSS3 transitions from Jquery Mobile. Let me know if should also post these.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT 2:**
Here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hDGVZ/9/

Comment: I don't see any CSS transition in this example. Can you post the relevant CSS / set up a demo?

Comment: Are you sure `status` is a real attribute? I've never heard of it and can't find any reference. Also, how is a transition (interpolation) supposed to take place between two binary (on/off) states? Usually you'd use the `opacity` CSS property or similar.

Comment: Can you post *reverse out pop* css classes? Are you sure you are using css3?

Comment: @RobW: Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hDGVZ/6/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to keep track of the state by a `status` attribute, because this is already available in jQuery's `:visible` pseudo-selector.

I have cleaned up your code, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hDGVZ/11/

```
$(document).on('click', '.trigger', function (event) {
    $('.popMe').each(function() { // For every .popUp element...
        var $this = $(this);
        // Clean-up, called upon finish of hide / show
        function onFinish() {
            $this.removeClass('reverse out pop in');
        }
        if ($this.is(':visible')) { // Visible?
            $this.addClass('reverse out').hide('fast', onFinish);
        } else {
            $this.addClass('ui-panel-active pop in').show('fast', onFinish);
        }
    });
});
```

If you don't want to implement this for every element, you can create a plugin:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hDGVZ/12/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.toggleVisible = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            // Clean-up, called upon finish of hide / show
            function onFinish() {
                $this.removeClass('reverse out pop in');
            }
            if ($this.is(':visible')) { // Visible?
                $this.addClass('reverse out').hide('fast', onFinish);
            } else {
                $this.addClass('ui-panel-active pop in').show('fast', onFinish);
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).on('click', '.trigger', function (event) {
    // Usage:
    $('.popMe').toggleVisible();
});
```

Comment: ah. :visible sounds good. Thanks for cleaning up. Let's see how I can mesh this with the rest of my script. Thx again!

Comment: @frequent I have added a simple plugin at the end of my answer. The new solution is as simple as calling `$('.popMe').toggleVisible();`.

Comment: Cool. Trying to plug it into my plugin (https://github.com/frequent/multiview/blob/master/multiview%20JQM%201.0.1/jquery.mobile.multiview.js)

Comment: @frequent Your code-formatting looks uncomfortable. Consider using http://jsbeautifier.com/, to set the indention correctly. **Also, if you use any material posted at Stack overflow, you have to mention the original source/author (see the license note at the bottom of this page).*